# QTP Extensibility. Cannot use standard methods

Tags: extension-methods, qtp

I implemented custom server for my custom edit field and after I added configuration to QTP I cannot see standard methods in InteliSence and even when I use them I get error 'object doesnt support property or method'

I've search help and internet inside and out but didn't find a thing. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What kind of extensibility are you using (Web, .NET, Java)?

Comment: Problem solved. I was using Exist in the wrong way.